# Qt creator creates trash files that doesn't exist

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04

If I'm working on let's say "file.cpp" and at one point the whole directory where the file is, is flooded with files such as "file.cpp.Yk2529", "file.cpp.bK2529". All of them ending on 2529. Interesting that they cannot be found through the terminal and can't be deleted because they don't exist they just stay there on the GUI directory. If someone has ever had this problem please help.

Comment: They could be temporary files from the compiler, with the number being the PID of the compiler process. Which compiler do you use? At least clang should use the temporary directory (usually /tmp) for this. Maybe an out-of-source build would also be a solution to not litter your source directory.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.